# Markov chain from Poisson process

Tags: probability, markov-chains, poisson-process

Let $K_t$ be a Poisson process with rate $1$ and $X_n=K_n-n$ $,  \  \  \        n\in \mathbb{N}$

Then we know that $X_n$ is a recurrent Markov chain. I am asked to determine whether the chain is null or positive recurrent.

I tried to compute the mean return time to zero, but, using the law of total probability, I got huge sums...

If $T=\min(n \geq 1 : X_n=0 |X_0 = 0) $ then I get:

$$ \mathbb{P}(T=k) = \sum_{t_1\not = 1}\sum _{t2\not = 2} \cdots \sum_{t_{k-1}\not = k-1} \mathbb{P}(K_1 = t_1)\mathbb{P}(K_2 = t_2)\cdots \mathbb{P}(K_{k-1}=t_{k-1})\mathbb{P}(N_k=k) $$

It does not look right....

How can I go on?

thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of (second part of) [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362190/question-about-markov-chain-derived-from-a-poisson-process) (although that part of the question is left unanswered in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 2):

Recall (from the proof of recurrence) that
$$
\mathrm{P} (X_n = 0\mid X_0=0) = \mathrm{P}(K_n = n) = \frac{n^{n}}{n!}e^{-n} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}, n\to\infty.
$$
Since $X$ is irreducible and aperiodic, if $X$ were positive recurrent, then this probability would converge to the value$^*$ $\pi_0>0$ of invariant distribution at zero. Since it converges to zero, $X$ is null recurrent.

---

$^*$ in fact, $\pi_0 = \frac{1}{\mathrm{E}[\tau]}$, where $\tau$ is the first time of the return to origin.