# Question about Markov chain derived from a Poisson process

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $(N_t)$ be a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$. Deﬁne $$
X_n = N_n − n,\quad\text{for }\; n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots
$$
Explain why $(X_n)$ is a Markov chain and give its transition probabilities. 
Using Stirling’s formula or otherwise, show that the chain is recurrent if and only if $\lambda = 1$. 
If $\lambda = 1$, is it null recurrent or positive recurrent?

I think the state space is all of the integers and the chain is irreducible.
I think the transition probabilities are 
$$
P(X_{n+1} = k+r \mid X_n = k) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{r+1}}{(r+1)!}
$$
for an integer $k$ and a non-negative integer $r$, and
$$
P(X_{n+1} = k-r \mid X_n = k) = e^{-\lambda}
$$
for $r = 1$ and $0$ otherwise.

I am having trouble with proving that the chain is recurrent, I think I should use the fact that a chain is recurrent if and only if 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_{ii}^{(n)}=\infty
$$
I am not sure how to do this, I tried finding the stationary distribution but this is very difficult.

Please help.

Comment: I've edited your question. Please check that this is what you intented to write.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I intended.

Comment: you will not succeed finding the stationary distribution, because I *think* this is null recurrent. this is really a weird way of phrasing this question because $N_t-\lambda t$ is what you call a compensated Poisson process.

Comment: @Lost1 I know you didn’t get around to addressing it fully in your answer, but, out of interest, what makes you suspect that the chain is null recurrent?

Comment: I can no longer remember why i thought that. It is possible to work out expected hitting time if we assume that time  and the process are continuous. These have explicit solutions. It is an application scale functions of spectrally negative (or positive) Levy processes. Take the example 1.3 http://www.maths.bath.ac.uk/~ak257/scale-review-final.pdf, set $\sigma=0$ and let $a=\mu=\lambda$ . $P(\zeta_i=1)=1$. apply theorem 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay have I have done this. I am not going to give you the solution, but I will offer you some hints:

You attempted approach to think about $p_{ii}^{(n)}$ is correct

$p_{ii}^{(0)}=1$ - agreed?

what is $p_{ii}^n$? well I think this is the probability of Poisson process jumping $n$ steps in time interval $n$. well the number of jumps in a time interval length $n$ is distributed as ....? so this probability is .... ?

The term should be a nice form $\bigg(\dfrac{n}{e}\bigg)^n/n!$ stirling's formula tell you $n!$ is approximately what? so the term behaves like $\dfrac{1}{n^\alpha}$ for $\alpha = ? <1$ therefore the series diverges.

Comment: @0998042 no worries

Comment: @0998042 btw, you can accept answers by pressing tick :P it will earn your a badge

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for the next part of the question? Is the chain positive or negative recurrence? I'm not sure how to find the mean return time (I normally use the stationary distribution for finite chains).

Comment: @0998042 oh !!!! I forgot about this! let me have a think about it.

Comment: @0998042 i have forgotten a little Markov Chain theory, is there any other equivalent condition to showing the positive recurrence rather than $E_i[T_i]=\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

I think we can try to solve the recurrence relation. I don't know if this will work, but here is an idea:

Let $t_i$ be expected amount of time to arrive at $0$ given you are currently at state $i$,.

$t_1 = p_{10} \times 1 + p_{11} (t_1+1) + p_{12} (t_2 +1) + p_{13} (t_3+1) + ... $

where $p_{ij}$ can be worked out and note $p_{ij} = p_{0,j-i}$ whenever $j\geq i$

get a system of these questions and see you can solve these. (though I hope there is an easier way) I will get back to you later. I need to do something for the next hours, sorry!